# Do tuples exist in twig? If so, how can I create one?

Tags: templating

Is there a tuple data structure in Twig? If there is, how do you create one?

Comment: Do you mean tuple or ternary operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)?

Comment: @Brad I mean tuple (first :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None that I'm aware of.  Since Twig ultimately gets compiled down to PHP and PHP doesn't have first-class citizen support for tuples, you're limited there.  You can quasi-fake them with [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the [list](https://www.php.net/list) function, but I don't think there is a Twig equivalent for list.

Answer (score 4):

No tuples per se. You can use arrays:

```
{% set a = ['a', 'b'] %}
{{ a[0] }}
```

You can use objects:

```
{% set o = {'first': 'a', 'second': 'b'} %}
{{ o.first }} or {{ attribute(o, 'first') }}
```

[merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) is very useful for constructing arrays and objects:

```
{% set a = a | merge(['c']) %}
{% set o = o | merge({'third': 'c'}) %}
```